# Truffle test, is it possible and useful to test types?

Tags: truffle-test

All is in the question : is it **possible** and **useful** and to test types ?
Or don't need to test it because Solidity is a statically typed programming language (it's already done).

I did many researches and couldn't find any answer.

```
function getCustomer(address _addr) external view returns (Customer memory) {
        return customers[_addr];
}
```

Then, is it possible to test the function parameter, if it's an address type ? : address _addr

Is it possible to test the return, if it's an address type ? : return customers[_addr]

For example, something like that (doesn't work) :

```
it("should be address type", async () => {
        await Instance.addCustomer(customer_02, { from: adminOwner });
        await expectRevert(Instance.getCustomer("BadAddressType", { from: Hacker }), "Error: invalid type address");
        });
```